# Jest testing src adds localhost to my string

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

My code creates a URL, which is then added as a `src` to a `script` element.

Implementation:

```
createScriptFunc() {
    const myVar = "bar";
    const myUrl = "www.example.com";
    const myScript = document.createElement("script");
    myScript.src = `${myUrl}?foo=${myVar}`;
    return myScript;
}
```

Pretty simple, and it works great. I get a result from calling the function back that looks like:

> `<script src="www.example.com?foo=bar></script>`

which is exactly what I want.

However when I test, I get an issue where the test tries to append `http://localhost` onto the string? My Jest test looks like this:

```
  describe("When createScriptFunc is called", () => {
    it("Should return script element with the correctly formed src", () => {
        expect(createScriptFunc()).toStrictEqual(expect.any(HTMLScriptElement)); // passes
        expect(createScriptFunc().src).toBe("www.example.com?foo=bar"); // does not pass
    });
  });
```

The `src` of my script element should be `www.example.com?foo=bar`, and this is the format that is output in the implementation. However in my test it seems to append `localhost` which I do not understand:

> Expected: "www.example.com?foo=bar"
>
> Received: "http://localhost/www.example.com?foo=bar"

As I said, it doesn't do this on the implementation, only in the Jest test. I don't understand why it's adding this localhost to the front of the src url. The rest is just right, where is the localhost being appended?

Comment: You're missing the `http://` bit so it thinks it's a relative URL.

Comment: Note the `.src` property is a property and not an attribute so it gets normalized when you assign to it. Chrome has the same behaviour here.